# Changing page orientation using data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

Is it possible to change the page orientation of a map using data driven pages in ArcGIS 10.1? After setting up the DDP I have 80 portrait maps with all the map elements set up correctly. About 10 of the maps actually need to be in landscape, but with all the same elements, so when I am exporting them, I would like to be able to indicate that those 10 should be generated in landscape.

Comment: I have a feeling this might not be possible, due to scaling issues, but I'd still like to hear how others have handled this.

Comment: Are you able to tag the features that need to be Landscape using an attribute of your index layer?  If so, could you use DDP in two "batches" to process Portrait then Landscape pages?

Comment: @PolyGeo no it's not possible to set the page orientation as an attribute of the DDP.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to set up two map documents, one for portrait and one for landscape. Your index layer will need a field to store the page orientation, something like "Pagesize". Then use the definition query on your index layer to limit which features will be included in that set of maps, e.g., `[Pagesize]="85x11P"` or `[PageSize]="85x11L"`.

It's pretty straightforward, but you will need to set up two separate map documents.

Comment: I've learnt a lot since I've asked this question, so I did come to the conclusion that I would need two different templates. I ended up creating a python script to pull everything together for exporting.

Comment: i wish that dynamic page size would be included in arcpy in next release, it is very important.