# Different page sizes in Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

Is it possible to set different page dimensions for maps within a single Data Driven Page series? For example have some of the series 11 x 17 inches, others 17 x 11 and a third 18 x 24.

The only solution I've come up with to date is split the series up into 3 sets, but then I'm jumping back and forth between them when symbols are tweaked and so on; something is always left out.

Comment: ...hmmm, maybe just not possible. See related  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39042/changing-page-orientation-using-data-driven-pages

Comment: Also relevant: [it is not currently possible to change page size using arcpy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41886/how-to-set-page-size-in-arcpy).